# How to read json array stored in mysql DB

Tags: mysql, json

I got a Json data stored in a column (rates) MySQL DB in this format:

```
[
  [
    {"value":null},
    {"value":"PaketA"}
  ],[
    {"value":"2,10"},
    {"value":"3,10"}
  ],[
    {"value":"4,10"},
    {"value":"3,15"}
  ],[
    {"value":"8,10"},
    {"value":"3,15"}
  ],[
    {"value":"12,00"},
    {"value":"3,20"}
  ],[
    {"value":"20,00"},
    {"value":"3,25"}
  ],[
    {"value":"31,50"},
    {"value":"3,30"}
  ]
]
```

I would like to get the value like this using sql:

```
Column 1 │ Column 2  
Null     │ PaketA  
2,10     │ 3,10  
4,10     │ 3,15  
etc...   │ etc...
```

Is this possible?

Whenever I tried to use json parsing command like:
select
rates[0] AS rate_0
FROM tablev

I always get:

> `Invalid argument types for function "GET"`

Thank you

Comment: select JSON_EXTRACT(@`json`,'$[0].value');.  I remember we have to use JSON_EXTRACT.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with json_extract. Assuming table name is JSON_TABLE and json cloumn is JSON_DATA

```
SELECT json_unquote(json_extract(JSON_DATA, '$[0][0].value')) AS Column_1, json_unquote(json_extract(JSON_DATA, '$[0][1].value')) AS Column_2 FROM JSON_TABLE;
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHT2q.png)

However this will only fetch the first "row". You can use a SP to iterate through the JSON array to fetch the rest.